# Cannot understand the before function of the Calendar class

Tags: java, calendar

I wrote the following code in Eclipse, I think all lines should print `true`, but only the second line print `true`, can anyone explain it to me?

```
    Date date = new Date();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);

    System.out.println(cal.before(date));
    System.out.println(cal.getTime().before(date));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code of the function `Calendar.before(Object when)`:

```
public boolean before(Object when) {
        return when instanceof Calendar
            && compareTo((Calendar)when) < 0;
    }
```

As you can see, it checks if given object is `Calendar`, and if it is not, like in your case, it returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.before()` takes a `Calendar` instance as a parameter. If you pass parameter of any other type (`Date` in this case) it just returns `false`. To make it work you would have to do something like this:

```
    Calendar nowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(cal.before(nowCalendar));
```